# Brackets showing posts info in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

l am following a ruby on rails tutorial. I am having my posts info show up in brackets beside the caption on the posts. if you know how to fix it, please help!

> Example=> "first post on PHOTOGRAM! [#<Post id: 1, caption: "first
>   post on PHOTOGRAM!", created_at: "2017-09-04 03:24:25", updated_at:
>   "2017-09-04 03:24:25", image_file_name: "instagram.jpg",
>   image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 64169,
>   image_updated_at: "2017-09-04 03:24:24">]"

posts controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.create(post_params)
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private

  def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:image, :caption)
  end
end
```

app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<h1> Photogram </h1>

<%= @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>
  <%= post.caption %>
<% end %>
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <%= f.text_field :caption %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the issue you're posting about but `<%= @posts.each do |post| %>` should use `<%` as an opening tag  instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `index.html.erb` to

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %>
  <%= post.caption %>
<% end %>
```

(Note the `=` that has been removed)

In ruby every statement has a return value. It might be `nil` but there is no `void` as known other programming languages.
And ERB the opening tag `<%=` will output the following ruby code. So this line of code will output all the posts in `@posts` as well.

(this Answer is basically what "max pleaner" said in his comment, just with some remarks and explanations)